# how to draw a dynamic chart with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts

I'm making an angular app for stock marketing.In this app the data is't the same and I should first check the type of data and after find out the data that should be show is chart data,then draw the chart 
if the content of page was known, then there was no problem I make a directive for chart and put it in view and just make data in controller .But problem is that I don't know how many chart do we have in each page maybe one chart,in one page and more chart in other so I can't make my view and I should make it after get data.
I make confuse and can't design my view I appreciate someone can help me.

Comment: How about use repeat in the view, which will be based on any array. Then in the loop use a <highcharts> directive. If you will have one chart, 1 will be printed, if 10, these amount will be pritned.

Comment: I use this way but I think it must be a better way